# |x|>S what is it on a number line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

this is probably super easy but I can't wrap my head around this can somebody graph this on a number line. I am trying to understand what $|x|>S$ looks like on a number line.

Comment: Do you know what $x>2$ looks like, for example?

Comment: all values greater than 2 I believe

Comment: Yes. So for positive $x, |x|>2$ is just all values greater than 2

Comment: Now for negative values of $x$, the absolute value just takes away the minus sign. Do you see why then for negative $x, |x|>2$ is the same thing as $x<-2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, $|x|>2 $ looks like this:
[image]

If you try filling in some numbers for $x$, and think about what $|x|$ then becomes, you will see why.

Ask me if you need more clarification!

Comment: Thanks. So |x| > S is basically like all the values to the left and to the right of the "s" region?

Comment: Yes, everything that's not between $-S$ and $S$. By the way, what do you thing of for example, $|x|=S$? Do you know what that would look like?

Comment: I have no idea can you tell me please? I can't seem to get it, if x could be any number essentially it just confuses me

Comment: Oh it is x=s and x=-s :)

Comment: Yep! *high fives*

Answer (score 0):

Note that $|x| \geq 0$, the same goes for $S $ as well. So, why don't you just draw a graph or look it up using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator)?

Answer (score 0):

On the real number line these are numbers from -infinity to -S and from S to +infinity

Comment: Do you understand why?

Comment: because absolute value is the distance from zero no matter the sign?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. But that might be confusing if you're asked to draw $|x+1|>2$, for example, since the symmetry is then not around 0 anymore

Answer (score 0):

For $S\ge 0$ it is equivalent to $x\lt-S\lor x\gt S$ so $x\in(-\infty,-S)\cup(S,\infty)$. Can you draw that? Watch out for the case $S=0$.

If $S\lt 0$, the solution set is all of the real line, i.e.$(-\infty,\infty)$. Can you draw that?